# How to find output of shell command run by fastlane action?

Tags: ios, fastlane

Sometimes it happens that a fastlane action throws an error like:

`ERROR [2016-11-06 03:34:20.16]: Shell command exited with exit status 48 instead of 0.`
I found troubleshooting difficult, as `--verbose` is not not verbose enough. By action I don't mean `sh` action, which is rather special case, but other fastlane actions e.g. `create_keychain`. The action `create_keychain` calls shell command `security create-keychain` and when it fails there is no clue what happened.

How do I find output of a shell command run by fastlane's action?
How do I find what shell command including all parameters is fastlane actually trying to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that there is no such option at the moment, but it should be easy to add it.
I have created git [issue #6878](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/6878) for it.

Answer (score 2):

The output of the shell command is printed out by default when you use the `sh` action. Alternatively you can also run the shell command directly yourself using backticks (standard Ruby)

```
puts `ls`
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, which helped me to improve the question. I am actually chasing a different scenario than you have described.